# Setting text to orientation in radius

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation

So here is my code in my activity class. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to get the text changed to the orientation in degrees. Nothing happens, it just stays at 0. Any suggestions?  This is the code in my activity class. I'm leaving out the details

```
public class WorkoutBuddy extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    SensorManager sm;
    MediaPlayer m;
    MediaPlayer r;
    TextView t1, t2, t3; 
    float x, y, z, gyroX, gyroY, gyroZ;
    float[] Rm = new float[16];
    float[] I = new float[16];
    boolean correctPosition = false, mPlayed = false, rPlayed = false;
    SensorManager mSensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Sensor magnetometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exercise_buddy);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        magnetometer = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD).get(0);
        t1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t3 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

      float[] geomagnetic;
      float[] gravity;
      float azimuth,pitch,roll;
      boolean havemag, haveacc;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            geomagnetic[0] = event.values[0];
            geomagnetic[1] = event.values[1];
            geomagnetic[2] = event.values[2];
            havemag = true;
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            gravity[0] = event.values[0];
            gravity[1] = event.values[1];
            gravity[2] = event.values[2];
            haveacc = true;
        }

        if (haveacc && havemag) {
            if (SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(Rm, I, gravity, geomagnetic)) {
                float[] result = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(Rm, result);

                azimuth = result[0];
                pitch = result[1];
                roll = result[2];
            }
        }

        t1.setText("Sensor reading for Y = "+ pitch);
        t2.setText("Sensor reading for Y = "+ roll);
        t3.setText("Sensor reading for Y = "+ azimuth);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        haveacc = false;
        havemag = false;
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        super.onResume();
    }




}
```

Comment: check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html).

Comment: i've already read it. That doesn't help. I want to know what I am doing wrong

Comment: @user3337034 : Added the entire code. The app keeps crashing on this activity